# Get VMWare session on local pc to use same ip range?

Tags: vmware-workstation

Trying to get vm instance of sql server 2008 in vm workstation to use the same ip range as the host. My PC is using 192.168.1.6 and my virtual machine is using 192.168.199.128 so it doest show up in my netgear router I was going port forward rdp and sql server on it.
VM Ware 2008 R2

**Edit**

Thanks for your answers but I manged to solve it to the extent of internet conenction but the ip address is still that of 192.168.199.128 so my router is still not finding it :-(

1 Open Virutal Network Configuration

2 Find the nic that is of vmnet0

3 Point it to your wifi adpeater or the ethernet

When i try to apply the ip address to my router i get the following error message

> This IP address should be in the same subnet as the LAN IP address

Still have an issue with this can anyone help ?

Ip Config /all from pc

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-M71FFCH83PK
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-26-82-48-B1-D1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox NDIS 6.0 Miniport Driver
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::753f:5eab:fd3d:ff84%22(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.255.132(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 705167399
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-FB-5D-64-40-61-86-65-76-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : @%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\ndisimplatform.sys,-530
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-26-82-48-B1-D7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5c66:fc2b:533:60cc%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.7(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 21 November 2015 22:01:42
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 22 November 2015 22:10:28
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 536876381
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-FB-5D-64-40-61-86-65-76-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::197b:85ca:9807:f08d%19(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 21 November 2015 22:10:33
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 21 November 2015 23:10:45
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 318787670
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-FB-5D-64-40-61-86-65-76-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-BE-98-B0-7A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BC4EBD2A-B24D-4CAD-9822-C0A3969EF20B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9A10FABC-346F-4BCA-B436-C112989A0781}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{21FADB3C-C5E4-4882-A533-6F1D4DAE3176}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

**Ipconfig /all results from vm machine**

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\david>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

```
  Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-B429VBF4FQE
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : localdomain

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connectio
n
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-3A-A8-F1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cc49:9705:bb6d:843b%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.128(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 21, 2015 10:13:11 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 21, 2015 10:43:11 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.2
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234884137
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-E2-9B-B5-00-0C-29-3A-A8-F1

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.2
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.localdomain:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\david>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-B429VBF4FQE
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : localdomain

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connectio
n
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-3A-A8-F1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cc49:9705:bb6d:843b%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.128(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 21, 2015 10:38:48 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 21, 2015 11:08:48 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.2
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234884137
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-E2-9B-B5-00-0C-29-3A-A8-F1

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.2
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.localdomain:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Have a look at bridged networking mode. That is what you are after.

Comment: tired that @EddieDunn but its saying now not connected mate yet my host pc has web access and all

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of network adapter to bridged instead of NAT.

The default is NAT, which will put your VMs on an isolated subnet.  If you use bridged mode, it will use the same network as your primary network adapter.

Comment: i tried that but then the we network icon rent red x and i rebooted the vm it stayed same trying it again here though

Comment: no luck it just saying now no network access

Comment: If the vm has a saved state you might encounter that when you change the adapter.  Did you properly  shutdown the vm or did you just close the VM while it was running?

Comment: I did a full restart

Comment: Is it saying no network access in VMWare or is Windows saying no vm access?  Another option would be to create a new VM with a bridged adapter and instead of starting over, point the new VM to the location of your existing VMDK image location.

Comment: in vmware windows 2008r2 instance

Comment: Are you using DHCP to hand out IP addresses on your primary network?  How many network adapters (physical) does the computer you are running VMware on have?

Comment: Can you add a secondary bridged adapter to the VM?

Comment: Please see my above edits

Comment: still having a probelm here have added my ipconfig i not sure why the subnet masks are different

Comment: Looks like they both have 255.255.255.0 to me.  Where do you see a difference?

Comment: when i go into my netgear router it says their not on the same subnet mask ? when i attemp to add them to port forwarding

Comment: I have included the ipconfig from my local pc as well where the vmware workstation pro is isntalled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31928/discussion-between-richie086-and-kymberly).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else the problem was indead my old install of vitrual box i uninstalled that and remove the bridges it created and now everything is fine i can see the vm in me network

Comment: It was virtual box that was causing the issue VMware?